# Creating a grouping variable for a survival model in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to plot a KM curve in `R` but first I need to fit the survival object. I have a dataset that consists of 100 rows where each row corresponds to a patient who is either in group A or group B. What I would like to do is to be able to plot (on the same plot) KM curves for group A versus group B versus group A+B (so everyone). The trouble that I am having is figuring out how to construct the group variable. I assume you can't do it in a single variable and so this is what I am trying, although it doesn't seem to be working correctly (I don't get everyone in group A and B).

```
set.seed(4)

n = 100
x = runif(n,0,1500)
y = runif(n,0,5)
survival = runif(n,1,1000)
censor = rbinom(n,1,.5)

dat = data.frame(x=x,y=y,survival=survival,censor=censor)

### Create a group indicator variable
# 1: Group A
# 2: Group B
# 3: Everyone else
group = rep(3,nrow(dat))
group[which(dat$x < 730.5)] = 1
group[which(dat$y >= 2)] = 2


### Kaplan Meier curves
# Need new group indicator variables
A = ifelse(group == 1,1,0)
B = ifelse(group == 2,1,0)
AB = ifelse(group != 3,1,0)


### Overall survival
os = survfit(Surv(dat$survival,dat$censor)~A + B + AB,data=dat)
```

So if you run the example and type `os` you will see that the sample size in AB  = 27, when what I want it to be is 17+56=73.

Comment: can you add sample values and reproduce scenario with data?

Comment: @bhavesh I added an example

Comment: you will not get every one in A and B, because few observation does not satisfy either conditions. 8th row got x = 1359.13823 and y = 1.06. so How you can group it?

Comment: @bhavesh That's group 3 which isn't part of AB. AB is everyone in groups 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong. The sample size AB = 1 is 73 (56+17), AB = 0 is 27. That seems correct with your data. You don't need "A + B + AB", though, you can just have "A + B" and it'll give you your three groups (A = 0 and B = 0, A = 1 and B = 0, A = 0 and B = 1).

Comment: @csgroen thanks that makes sense! however, how do I get it to group it such that it's A = 1 and B = 1, A = 1 and B = 0, A = 0 and B = 1? Because when I go to plot it I want to see the three groups A, B, and AB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to create a new column indicating the group (A or B) the row belongs to, and bind this with the whole population (A+B). 
Then simply run the model against the group.

```
# Create a new variable to indicate the group and drop the group you don't need.
dat$group = "C"
dat$group = ifelse( dat$x < 730.5, "A", dat$group )
dat$group = ifelse( dat$y >= 2, "B", dat$group )
dat = subset( dat, dat$group != "C" )

# Bind the sample with the population
dat2 = dat
dat2$group = "AB"
data = rbind( dat2, dat )

table( data$group )
# A AB  B 
# 17 73 56 

# Plot 
plot( survfit(Surv(data$survival,data$censor)~group,data=data) )
```